# How to overflow content from the top and clip it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I Have positioned the UI elements but have no idea how to achieve that *corner* clip effect. Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/Lines.png'),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Center(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/Logo.png'),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/Lines.png'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I have:

[image: What I have]

Desired effect:

[image: Desired effect]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "corner clip effect". Could you add some detail to describe the desired effect? Also, does the image show what you are currently getting, or what you are trying to achieve. Providing both is helpful if possible

Comment: @cameron1024 My mistake, I've added another image. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the widgets in a `stack` and offset them.

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              child: Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    right: -35,
                    top: -35,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/Lines.png'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Center(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/Logo.png'),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              child: Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    left: -35,
                    bottom: -35,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/Lines.png'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```